# Expose normal http endpoint in NestJS Microservices

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, microservices, nestjs

I have this microservice written with NestJs:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || '5000', 10);

  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(ApplicationModule, {
    transport: Transport.TCP,
    options: { host: '0.0.0.0', port }
  });
  app.listen(() => console.log(`Microservice is listening on port ${port}`));
}
bootstrap();
```

But now I need to implement an endpoint `/metrics` for Prometheus. So the question is how do I do this with NestJs microservice

From [this](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1627) issue I get the impression that it is not possible. Is this true and if so, is there a workaround I can use?

I tried to apply middleware as follows

```
Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, DBService],
})
export class ApplicationModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(MetricsMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('/metrics') // Also tried '*'
  }
}
```

But when I do `curl http://localhost:5000/metrics` nothing happens, the middleware is not called

```
@Injectable()
export class MetricsMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    constructor() {}

    use(req, res, next) {
        console.log('yes');
        next();
    }
}
```

Update: [This issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/853) will also not help :(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want your application to support both http requests and a microservice, you can create a [hybrid application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application).

```
// Create your regular nest application.
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);

// Then combine it with your microservice
const microservice = app.connectMicroservice({
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: { host: '0.0.0.0', port: 5000 }
});

await app.startAllMicroservices();
await app.listen(3001);
```

Comment: What if I want all my microservices to be able to support http requests, but also be able to communicate with each other. Is this possible?

Comment: @Shirohige Have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53996635/4694994

Comment: Wait, this already is a hybrid application... What do you mean? They can all communicate with each other either via the "microservice protocol" or http.

Comment: So I'm trying to expose endpoints to my web application from multiple microservices. For example, if I do a GET request on /users, it will hit an endpoint from the Users service, and if I do a GET requests on /notifications, it will hit an endpoint from the Notifications service.
With the hybrid application, it seems to me that only the 'main' app that connects all microservices is able to expose endpoints and connect to the other microservices, or should all other microservices also be instantiated with the hybrid approach?

Comment: @Shirohige But are you using any other transport protocol besides your http requests? If not, simply create all your microservices as regular applications. Only if you want to use an additional transport protocol besides http you need to create a hybrid application.

Comment: It's rather hard to understand your requirements in the limited space of a comment. Maybe consider opening a new question.

Comment: I'm new to NestJS and microservices overall. I will go with your suggestion and just create multiple regular applications, thanks very much!

Comment: `startAllMicroservicesAsync()` is now **deprecated**. you can use the alternative similarly: `await app.startAllMicroservices();`